# Coefficients in quasibinomial regression and model prediction plots

Tags: regression, data-visualization, model, quasi-likelihood

I'm using two quasibinomial models. In the first model, the dependent variable is the proportion x of successes in experiment A. In the second model, the dependent variable is the proportion y of successes in experiment B. Both models have the same variable of interest and the same nuisance variables as independent variables.

Looking at the two model predictions plots about the relationships between the dependent variable and the variable of interest, I'm a bit puzzled. In both plots, the model prediction looks like a straight line. What's strange is that, despite model 1 has a regression coefficient two times greater than that of model 2, the slope of the straight line appears only slightly greater for model 1 than for model 2.

Can this happen with a quasibinomial model, or does it necessarily reveal an error of some kind?

Thanks.